# Change Permalinks to Anchor Links When Using Bootstrap Navwalker

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I'm currently using the Bootstrap Navwalker for a menu on a one-page theme that I'm building.

At the moment, this is generating full urls

```
 http://www.fulladdress.com/pagename
```

when I'd only like it to create

```
 #pagename
```

I'm wondering whether I need to adjust wp_bootstrap_navwalker, or if theres something I can append to wp_nav_menu.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to this by changing the following (line 90) in the wp_bootstrap_navwalker file

```
$atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
```

to...

```
$atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? '#' . $item->title : '';
```

which makes permalink take the page title instead of the url.

Then made sure that each section of my theme had an id= that referenced its own title:

```
 <section id="<?php
    $pagename=excerpt;
    $post = get_post($id);
    $title = apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title);
    echo $title;
    ?>">
```

I'm sure there are better solutions out there, though! Eager to hear.